# how to get a value of a json http response in azure logic app

Tags: azure

I'm trying to get "id" value set to a variable by parsing the below output sample. The REST API call will return multiple values as shown below and I'm interested in only getting the "id" value for the particular name that users has provided/set as input in the workflow earlier either by a parameter value or by initializing a variable. How do I do this value extraction in azure logic app?

Any help much appreciated.

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "xyz-List",
    "data": {
      "urls": [
        "*.test1.com",
        "*.test2.com"
      ],
      "type": "exact"
    },
    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
    "modify_time": "2022-06-29T21:05:27.000Z",
    "modify_type": "Created",
    "pending": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "abc-List",
    "data": {
      "urls": [
        "www.mytesting.com"
      ],
      "type": "exact"
    },
    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
    "modify_time": "2022-06-29T21:05:27.000Z",
    "modify_type": "Created",
    "pending": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "azure-list",
    "data": {
      "type": "exact",
      "urls": [
        "www.xyz.com",
        "www.azure-test.com"
      ],
      "json_version": 2
    },
    "modify_by": "admin@xyz.com",
    "modify_time": "2022-09-26T01:25:20.000Z",
    "modify_type": "Edited",
    "pending": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at stackoverflow.com due programming is there on focus. on here there might some but not mostly specific

Comment: thank you, I posted it over there now as well.